# Invalid Directory

Tags: python, filepath

I am trying to make a dataset like MNIST, of pashto digits but i am getting this error

> for filename in os.listdir(path):
>
> NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:

my code is here

```
          Names = [['D:\\myResearchData\\jpg_to_mnist\\training_images','train'], ['D:\\myResearchData\\jpg_to_mnist\\test-images','test']]

          for name in Names:

                data_image = array('B')
                data_label = array('B')

                FileList = []
                    for dirname in os.listdir(name[0])[1:]: 
                        path = os.path.join(name[0],dirname)
                        for filename in os.listdir(path):
                            if filename.endswith(".bmp"):
                                FileList.append(os.path.join(name[0],
                                               dirname,filename))

shuffle(FileList) # Usefull for further segmenting the validation set
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with with the dataset setup, but did a brief search for you. https://forums.fast.ai/t/notadirectoryerror-winerror-267-the-directory-name-is-invalid-data-bts-valid-features-npy/19657. Hope it helps.

Comment: I suspect that `os.listdir(path)` is sometimes being called on a file, not a directory, which would give you that error.Probably should check if `path` is a file or directory before that call.